# Scroll windows didn't scroll separately, and the height is not fixed on screen in Html/Css/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Their are two windows, one is contact and the other one is message area and in bottom their is textarea(Message typing area).

**1) How to Fixed the height of Contact and Message area on screen and they scroll separately?**

**2) How to fit the textarea just on the bottom of message area (now it's come in the bottom of contact area)?**

**HTML**

```
<div class="container bootstrap snippet">
    <div class="tile tile-alt" id="messages-main">
        <div class="ms-menu">
            <div class="ms-user clearfix">
                <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar1.png" alt="" class="img-avatar pull-left">
                <div>Signed in as <br> m-hollaway@gmail.com</div>
            </div>


            <div class="list-group lg-alt" id="scrollContact">

                <a class="list-group-item media" href="">
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar2.png" alt="" class="img-avatar">
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <div class="list-group-item-heading">Davil Parnell</div>
                    </div>
                </a>

                <a class="list-group-item media" href="">
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar3.png" alt="" class="img-avatar">
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <div class="list-group-item-heading">Ann Watkinson</div>
                    </div>
                </a>

                <a class="list-group-item media" href="">
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar4.png" alt="" class="img-avatar">
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <div class="list-group-item-heading">Marse Walter</div>
                    </div>
                </a>

            </div>


        </div>

        <div class="ms-body">
            <div class="action-header clearfix">
                <div class="visible-xs" id="ms-menu-trigger">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </div>

                <div class="pull-left hidden-xs">
                    <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar2.png" alt="" class="img-avatar m-r-10">
                    <div class="lv-avatar pull-left">

                    </div>
                    <span>David Parbell</span>
                </div>

                <ul class="ah-actions actions">

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                            <i class="fa fa-sort"></i>
                        </a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Latest</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Oldest</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>                             
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                        </a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Delete</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Block Messages</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Report as Spam</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

    <div id="scrollMessage">

            <div class="message-feed media">
                <div class="pull-left">
                    <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar1.png" alt="" class="img-avatar">
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <div class="mf-content">
                        Quisque
                    </div>
                    <small class="mf-date"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 20/02/2015 at 09:00</small>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="message-feed media">
                <div class="pull-left">
                    <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar1.png" alt="" class="img-avatar">
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <div class="mf-content">
                        Quisque
                    </div>
                    <small class="mf-date"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 20/02/2015 at 09:00</small>
                </div>
            </div>

            </div>

        <div class="msb-reply clearfix">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
                                           <textarea placeholder="What's on your mind..."></textarea>
                                           <button id="button3" title="Send"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i></button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-8">
                                            <button id="button1" title="Add File's"><i class="fa fa-file"></i></button>
                                            <button id="button2" title="Add Photo's"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i></button>
                                        </div>



          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-family: Roboto,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #767676;
    background-color: #edecec;
    width:100%;
}

.container{
    width:100%;
}

#scrollContact {
    height: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color:#eee;
}

#scrollMessage {
    height: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#messages-main {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#messages-main:after, #messages-main:before {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
#messages-main .ms-menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 240px;
}
@media (min-width:768px) {
    #messages-main .ms-body {
    padding-left: 240px;
}
}@media (max-width:767px) {
    #messages-main .ms-menu {
    height: calc(100% - 58px);
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 58px;
}
#messages-main .ms-menu.toggled {
    display: block;
}
#messages-main .ms-body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
}
#messages-main .ms-user {
    padding: 15px;
    background: #f8f8f8;
}
#messages-main .ms-user>div {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px 5px 0 15px;
    font-size: 11px;
}

#messages-main #ms-compose {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 120px;
    z-index: 1;
    right: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .28);
}
#ms-menu-trigger {
    user-select: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 19px;
}
#ms-menu-trigger i {
    font-size: 21px;
}
#ms-menu-trigger.toggled i:before {
    content: '\f2ea'
}
.fc-toolbar:before, .login-content:after {
    content: ""
}
.message-feed {
    padding: 20px;
}
#footer, .fc-toolbar .ui-button, .fileinput .thumbnail, .four-zero, .four-zero footer>a, .ie-warning, .login-content, .login-navigation, .pt-inner, .pt-inner .pti-footer>a {
    text-align: center;
}
.message-feed.right>.pull-right {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.message-feed:not(.right) .mf-content {
    background: #03a9f4;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
.message-feed.right .mf-content {
    background: #eee;
}
.mf-content {
    padding: 12px 17px 13px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 80%;
}
.mf-date {
    display: block;
    color: #B3B3B3;
    margin-top: 7px;
}
.mf-date>i {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}
.msb-reply {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    right:0px;
    width:100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
    background: #f8f8f8;
}
.four-zero, .lc-block {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 11px rgba(0, 0, 0, .27);
}
.msb-reply textarea {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 13px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    resize: none;
    height: 60px;
    background: 0 0;
}
#button1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 40px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #2196f3;
    background: 0 0;
}

#button2 {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 40px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #2196f3;
    background: 0 0;
}

#button3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 60px;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #2196f3;
    background: 0 0;
}
#button3:hover {
    background: #f2f2f2;
}

.img-avatar {
    height: 37px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 37px;
}
.list-group.lg-alt .list-group-item {
    border: 0;
}
.p-15 {
    padding: 15px!important;
}
.btn:not(.btn-alt) {
    border: 0;
}
.action-header {
    position: relative;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    padding: 15px 13px 15px 17px;
}
.ah-actions {
    z-index: 3;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 7px;
    position: relative;
}
.actions {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.actions>li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.actions:not(.a-alt)>li>a>i {
    color: #939393;
}
.actions>li>a>i {
    font-size: 20px;
}
.actions>li>a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.ms-body{
    background:#fff;    
}
#ms-menu-trigger {
    user-select: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 19px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#ms-menu-trigger, .message-feed.right {
    text-align: right;
}
#ms-menu-trigger, .toggle-switch {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
}
```

**JSFIDDLE:-** https://jsfiddle.net/apf5bjeL/

Comment: add max height on outer to scrolling section

Comment: yes, it is working but their is another issue, that when the height of one side is increase the other one is also increasing with it, why?

Comment: And they scroll on one scroller not separately, on main scroller while they have the separately but it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to fix height instead of auto:

```
#scrollContact {
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    background-color:#eee;
}

#scrollMessage {
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```